# How to convert Android XML drawable to image?

Tags: android, xml, image, android-shape

My android guys are using the following XML for an image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
    <solid android:color="#5ab9a3"/>
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#cc5ab9a3"
        android:startColor="#5ab9a3" />
</shape>
```

Can I somehow convert this description into an image directly?

Comment: xml as image? Are you talking about something like svg?

Comment: Yeah, please clarify what kind of data you are working with

Comment: Please post one of the XML here so that we will get good idea about your question

Comment: This question along with your question history indicate that you really need to read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the Replay Please see Updated One.

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks for the replay Yes I am very poor in written skills. And Thanks for the advise definitely i will read your Ref.

Comment: Not sure what this format is. The best way might be to find out what the format is called (it is XML, but it has to have a different name, too) and then Google for ways to convert it to an image

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for the replay. But can you please tell me one thing can we able to work with xml file in xcode.

Comment: You mean, use that XML above to build an iOS interface? I don't know, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: I've rewritten, reformatted, and retagged your question so that it should be better able to elicit helpful answers.  I'm guessing (and we shouldn't have to guess -- again, read [ask] -- so if I'm wrong, feel free to roll-back my edit) that you just need a raster image that matches the one specified in the Android `shape` declaration.  If this is a one-off, maybe just screen capture it once drawn in the Android app or simulator?

Comment: @kjhughes Yes thats what i need. Thanks for pointing me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shape drawable, which is used for making simple shapes in Android, from simple instructions, like a "SVG-lite".

I am unfamiliar in any way other than android for rendering this into an image, but if you want to use it somewhere else you can turn this into png/jpg by converting it to a bitmap and putting it on device storage.

But keep in mind that it will be an image, and not keep SVG-like functions like keeping the line width when resizing the image etc which would be useful if you are using it for a background for containers of different sizes.

Your best bet if you want to keep this type of function would be to use the information in this xml somewhere else, like a similar system, or SVG. You know the colors. You know how the gradient is set up. And you know the corners are rounded with a radius of 7-something-units.

Comment: Thanks for the Replay your saiying that i need to convert my xml to png/jpg right.

Comment: Depends on where you are going to use it, if the image is always going to be the same size (or sizes, if you generate more than one image from bitmap) png/jpgs should be fine, but if not you should probably try something else.

Comment: If you need to use this for iOS development, I don't think you can use this, but you can use the information in it to make something similar.

Look into Bézier paths and iOS drawing concepts, here are some links:

[drawing concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW1)  
  ,  
[bezier paths](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html)

Comment: Yes your right Thanks for the information.and above links not necessary in my case